# Probability of choosing at least one card

Tags: probability

[image: the question]

REFER TO PART 3 (iii) OF QUESTION.

following is my solution :

[image: the solution]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah your solution is correct

We can solve it more easily in the following way . let $p(at\ least\ one\ B)$ is required probability which can also be written as

$=$ $1 - p(No \ B \ is\  selected)$

$=$ $1 - (6/8)*(5/7)$

$= 1 -(15/28)$

$= 13/28$